# Customer account dashboard showing orders from wrong customer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer

The `recent orders` section of the customer dashboard of my website is showing the orders for the wrong customer. However, on the `sales/orders` section of the Magento backend are correctly associated.

All I've done recently is migrating the database from Magento 1.9.0.1 to a new database for the website running Magento 1.9.1.1

Could anyone please help me solving this?